# Error 404 in react native using axios - Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to pull some data from an API here in Brazil, but it is returning the following error:

```
Object {
  "_link": "/v1/campeonatos/2/fases/56",
  "decisivo": false,
  "eliminatorio": true,
  "fase_id": 56,
  "ida_e_volta": false,
  "nome": "Segunda Fase",
  "status": "finalizado",
}

Request failed with status code 404
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:16:9 in settle
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:52:6 in handleLoad
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:566:23 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

And this is my code:

```
const Fase = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props
  const { route } = props
  const { item: fase } = route.params
  const { campeonato_id } = route.params
  const { campeonato } = route.params
  const { fase_id } = fase.fase_id
  const [dados, setDados] = useState([])
  const getDados = () => {
    console.log(fase)
    axios.get('https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/campeonatos/2/fases/55' + campeonato_id + '/fases/' + fase_id, { 'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer live_f681927263cdc6a0e5ac9774c0a4b0' } })
      .then((retorno) => {
        var arr = [];
        Object.keys(retorno.data.chaves).forEach((chave, index) => {
          Object.keys(retorno.data.chaves[chave].ida).forEach((i, index) => {
            arr.push(retorno.data.chaves[chave].ida[i])
          })
        })
        Object.keys(retorno.data.chaves).forEach((chave, index) => {
          Object.keys(retorno.data.chaves[chave].volta).forEach((i, index) => {
            arr.push(retorno.data.chaves[chave].volta[i])
          })
        })
```

How can I solve this?
I do not understand why this error, being that on other screens I am also doing the same way and the data is being brought correctly.
I'm using react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the variables to wrong path in your route.

The link you are using is: 
`'https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/campeonatos/2/fases/55' + campeonato_id + '/fases/' + fase_id`

Maybe what you want is:

`'https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/campeonatos/'+campeonato_id+'/fases/' + fase_id`

If you would like to change the sintax from your code to a modern javascript version you could use the template string pattern.

```
const endpoint = `https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/campeonatos/${campeonato_id}/fases/${fase_id}`
```